# Postgres “missing FROM-clause entry” error on query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use this query in Postgres:

```
SELECT ean, count(nif)
FROM produto P, fornece_sec F
WHERE P.ean = F.ean
GROUP BY ​P.ean
HAVING count(nif) > 1;
```

I get this error:

ERROR:  column reference "ean" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT ean, count(nif)

If I change the query to:

```
SELECT P.ean, count(nif)
FROM produto P, fornece_sec F
WHERE P.ean = F.ean
GROUP BY ​P.ean
HAVING count(nif) > 1;
```

Appears another error:

ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "​p"
LINE 4: GROUP BY ​P.ean

Those two tables are created this way:

```
create table produto (
ean char(13) not null unique,
design varchar(255) not null,
categoria varchar(80) not null,
forn_primario char(9) not null,
data date not null,
constraint ean_size CHECK (Length(ean)=13),
constraint pk_produto primary key(ean),
constraint fk_produto_categoria foreign key(categoria) references categoria(nome) ON DELETE CASCADE,
constraint fk_produto_fornecedor foreign key(forn_primario) references fornecedor(nif));

create table fornece_sec (
nif char(9) not null,
ean char(13) not null,
constraint pk_fornece_sec primary key(nif, ean),
constraint fk_fornece_sec_fornecedor foreign key(nif) references fornecedor(nif),
constraint fk_fornece_sec_produto foreign key(ean) references produto(ean) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Note: the attribute nif in fornece_sec table is the same type of the attribute forn_primario in the product table.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` seems to contain unicode, not ASCII.  Maybe the P is non-ASCII character that looks like P.

Comment: You've tagged sql-server, postgresql **and** mysql here. They are all different products. Which are you using..?

Comment: Please tag properly.  MySQL <> Postgres <> SQL Server

Comment: Also use proper `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

This probably has nothing to do with it, but maybe try explicitly declaring the INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT P.ean, count(nif)
FROM produto P
INNER JOIN fornece_sec F ON P.ean = F.ean
GROUP BY ​P.ean
HAVING count(nif) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tommy was right:

"Your GROUP BY seems to contain unicode, not ASCII. Maybe the P is non-ASCII character that looks like P."